# AngularJS multiple $http calls, with multiple results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a LIST of Id's and I want **all** of them to contact my API.

The way I did it is like this:

```
 var someFunct = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < Apples.length; i++) {
       var Apple = Apples[i];
        $http.get("APIUrl" + Apple.Id).
        success(function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Appleseeds.length; i++) {

                if(Apple.Appleseeds.Id == response.Appleseeds.Id)
                {
                    Apple.Size = response.Appleseeds.Size;
                }
            }               
        })

    }
```

So the problem is that `Apple[2]` has changed value, where `Apple[0]` and `Apple[1]` stay untouched. `response.Appleseeds` have their own list of Id's. So I need to change the Size of ALL THE APPLES not just `Apple[2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, use a closure instead:

```
var someFunct = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < Apples.length; i++) {
        (function (Apple) {
            $http.get("APIUrl" + Apple.Id)
            .success(function (response) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.Appleseeds.length; i++) {

                    if (Apple.Appleseeds.Id == response.Appleseeds.Id) {
                        Apple.Size = response.Appleseeds.Size;
                    }
                }
            });
        })(Apples[i]);
    }
};
```

Because `http` doesn't happen instantly, by the time the last success has happened in your code apple has been changed. By wrapping it in a closure you make it so that each call has it's own private Apple.

Comment: Its working! thank you ! in 3 min i give you "Correct answer" :D Need to read about closure..

Answer (score 1):

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var someFunct = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Apples.length; i++) {
    $http.get("APIUrl" + Apples[i].Id).
    success(function (response) {
         deferred.resolve(response)              
    })
    return deferred.promise;
 }
}

someFunct().then(function(d)){
    // write your code here
   }
```